# Is it possible to delete backfaces as opposed to hiding them?

Tags: modeling, mesh

So I’m just starting out in Blender - I have 50+ textured and animated models (md3 format) which I didn’t make but need to fix up to render properly in a game engine.  I’ve managed to find md3 import/export scripts so have gotten over that first hurdle.

The issue I have is that my models don’t render correctly in a 3D game but in Blender look “correct” when I enable back face culling mode. Can my models be permanently fixed in Blender to in effect replicate this culling of back faces? If so I am sincerely hoping a more expert user can provide procedures on the step(s) involved?

I’m a complete newbie with Blender - I’ve tried to fix my models both in MilkShape 3D (was promising but removed all animations from my md3s) and Misfit Model 3D (no joy).  I’ve tried flipping normals and other tweaks without success.

Comment: Firstly, what game engine? secondly, an image in the game engine of what is wrong and images of the model in Blender including Riggs and normal direction in edit mode. I know that backface culling is automatic in unity, but if it is a different game engine, it may not do so. Maybe look into activating backface culling in your render engine.

Answer (score 2):

## It is impossible to delete backfaces, since they are only a concept in rendering algorithms - there is nothing to delete

Backface culling is a shading feature of the render engine that you are using. Back faces are not in any way stored with 3d data so there is nothing to delete. Backface is the back of a regular face that is determined by which direction the surface is facing or in other words - surface normals, that are definitely already included in your models when you export them from Blender or pretty much any other 3d app. No other information about back faces than surface normals is saved with the models so there is nothing more that can be done inside Blender. This features should be turned on or off in the game engine you are using. Backfaces might not be displayed by default in some rendering scenarios so it may also not be considered a feature at all, but actually the lack of another feature - backface shading, or double sided shading. It depends on how you look at it and how the shading works in a specific render engine.